# The use of prepositions at the end without verb

Tags: preposition, sentence-structure

Can someone explain the following example and give others with other prepositions if there exists :

> Ihr früher Tod hätte in den meisten Fällen durch einfache Mittel verhindert werden können - zum Beispiel sauberes Wasser, Impfungen und gute Versorgung ***vor***. - Deutsche Welle.

I don't know if it's somehow the same as:

> von mir aus

or

> von etwas her

can you explain please the use of this kind of structures ?

Comment: What kind of structure are you talking about?

Comment: like : von mir aus , or von etwas her .. sometimes ab is used, I don't remember where I read it ; I mean when the preposition is in the end of the sentence but without verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotation is not complete. It actually reads

> Ihr früher Tod hätte in den meisten Fällen durch einfache Mittel verhindert werden können, die für uns in Deutschland selbstverständlich sind – zum Beispiel sauberes Wasser, Impfungen und gute Versorgung vor, während und nach der Geburt.

Thus, *vor* is part of the list *„vor, während und nach der Geburt“* (“before, during, and after birth”).

Comment: Aha!, thanks, I got it , but Your explication doesn't go throughout the second part of my question, can you explain please the use of the prepositions in the last of sentences ? ( or part of sentences ) . ( like the two later examples I stated in my question )